# Should I authenticiate with Azure Active Directory or Windows Active Directory or Other?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm building a C# .net Framework 4.6.1 WPF application that will run on azure virtual machines. I would like the application to online run on my domain/virtual machines and would like the experience for the user to be seamless(not requiring them to login in twice). Should I authenticate by grabbing credentials from windows AD(since it is managed from the Azure AD tenet) and if user is logged in and apart of the appropriate group allow access or pass those credentials to azure AAD single sign on and receive verification from that? Or should I be approaching this from a different angle entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The idea about syncing your AD with azure AD is that users should be able to signin with the same account as their local accounts on services that are in Azure. So you can technically have any application in Azure using Azure AD as the mode of authentication and it should be single sign on for them. For eg I create a web application that has Azure AD as the mode of authentication and I am connected to the corporate network who's AD has been synced with Azure AD then you can just use Single Sign On. Please refer to this link to learn more about it [Azure AD SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso)